# Multi-Process NodeJs Worker gets not executed

Tags: node.js, typescript, multiprocessing, worker, node-worker-threads

## Issue with Accessing Methods in Worker Threads with Node.js and TypeScript

I'm currently facing a challenge related to accessing methods within a Worker Thread in a Node.js application. The setup involves utilizing Node.js 18 stable along with TypeScript and ESM. The primary goal is to invoke a method within the Worker Thread, with the intent of having it execute the run method concurrently. However, I'm encountering errors, specifically those associated with method cloning.

Initially, I attempted to use the 'piscina' library for this purpose, but the issue persisted. Consequently, I decided to explore using Node.js' built-in worker_threads module.

#### Code Structure

Here's the structure of my current code:

```
if (isMainThread) {
    const workerFilePath = path.join(moduleDir, 'botWorker.js'); // Ensure the correct file extension

    const botPromises = botService.botList.map((bot) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const worker = new Worker(workerFilePath, {
                workerData: { bot: bot },
            });

            worker.on('message', (message) => {
                resolve(message);
                worker.terminate();
            });

            worker.on('error', (error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    });
```

### Debugging and File Targeting

While trying to debug the issue, I encountered some confusion regarding whether the correct file is being targeted. For instance, the botWorker.ts file is written in TypeScript (.ts). Despite being advised to register ts-node, the problem remains unresolved.

Here's an excerpt from my botWorker.ts:

```
// botWorker.ts
import { parentPort } from 'worker_threads';
import { Bot } from './model/Bot';

parentPort?.on('message', async (message) => {
    if (message && message.bot) {
        const result = await message.bot.run();
        parentPort?.postMessage({ botName: message.botName, result });
    }
});
```

#### Request for Assistance

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address this perplexing issue. Specifically, I'm seeking guidance on debugging the file targeting issue and resolving the method cloning error.

Thank you kindly for your time and assistance in advance!